# Edit Google form responses through Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I know it's not possible to directly edit the Google form response by editing the Google sheet, but I was hoping to have a work around by using this https://xfanatical.com/blog/how-to-edit-google-forms-responses-in-the-spreadsheet/#source-code.
The script generates a link through which the response can be edited, but I was hoping that when I change a response in the sheet, it would be updated in the link as well and I would only have to hit the resend button.

Does anyone know an easy solution where I can update responses in the sheet and they also will be visible in the form?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to 'prefill' a google form using data from a google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108511/is-it-possible-to-prefill-a-google-form-using-data-from-a-google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a link with the responses already on the form, as you mentioned, but also using Apps Script you can get the responses from the Sheet and pre-fill the form with those responses.

The workflow would be:

- Edit the answers on the Sheet
- Get those answers on Apps Script
- Pre-fill the form with the new answers
- Create the link to the form with the new answers

Reference links:

- [createResponse()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#createresponse)
- [Class FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)
- [toPrefilledUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#toprefilledurl)

Also you can check this previously solved question from Stack Overflow:

- [Prefill a Google Form using data inside Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290365/prefill-a-google-form-using-data-inside-google-spreadsheet)