# Autocomplete Google Form based on values in spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm writing a script to autocomplete some fields in a Google Form based on a field that has started to be filled out. For argument's sake, let's say it's `address`. So when a user fills the form out like so:

[image: form1]

And if in a spreadsheet called `defaults` there is a row with this address:

[image: sheet1]

**Not only** that field is updated, but any other fields that match are, too (like `name` and `email`).

Does anyone have any suggestions for me? My research has turned up [nothing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) [too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108511/is-it-possible-to-prefill-a-google-form-using-data-from-a-google-spreadsheet) useful for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to create an autocomplete field in a live Google Form.  You can create a stand alone Apps Script Web App using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.  You could even style it to make it look like a Google Form.

Comment: That's good enough for me. I don't suppose there's an easy way to throw the Google Forms functionality I've already built into a Apps Script web app?

Comment: Any code that you have in something like an "On Form Submit" trigger can be used for the most part.  You'd want to create a different function name, and call it with `google.script.run.myFunctionName()` client side API.  Basically, any server side `.gs` code can be reused, the difference is, you need to collect the form values, and send them to the server from your form.  As far as things like "Go to Page" based on an answer,  "No" you can't port that over.  It's more work, to design the form yourself, but you have many more possibilities.  And things like the Edit URL, aren't built in.