# pre-fill google form from google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a student registration form, there's student id which is a required field. I have a google apps script function which tells if this student is registered for any class or not. Is there a way to auto-fill the field course registered via calling the google apps script function yes or no.

Comment: Yes.  You can build a prefilled URL in code.  A prefilled URL will fill all or some questions.  A Form submitted from a prefilled URL will submit a new response, as opposed to editing an existing response.

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086855/autofill-a-google-form-fields-based-on-a-spreadsheet

Comment: Above link is no longer available. This answer gives URL example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108511/is-it-possible-to-prefill-a-google-form-using-data-from-a-google-spreadsheet

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can create a pre filled response with the forms ID, not that the pre filled fields are showed in the URL

```
Function formPrefill(formId){
    var form = FormApp.openById(formId);
    try{
    var items = form.getItems();
    var formResponse = form.createResponse();
    // Prefill SessionId
    var formItem = "SOMETHING HERE"
    var response = formItem.createResponse(sessionId);
    formResponse.withItemResponse(response);

    //--------ANOTHER FIELD-------------
    formItem = items[4].asMultipleChoiceItem();
    response = formItem.createResponse('YOUR FIELD NAME');
    formResponse.withItemResponse(response);

    }catch(e){catch an error here}


}
```

check https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#createresponse