# Prefill Google Form date field with date from calendar invite

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-forms

I'm planning a series of events with a recurring Google Calendar invite. The calendar invite description contains a link to a Google Form to collect feedback about the event. In the form you currently have to manually enter the date of the event for which you want to provide feedback.

Google Form allows to create URLs to the form that prefills some values.

Is there a way to dynamically add the date of an individual event to the form URL in the event description, so that participants can access the feedback form for the individual event directly from the meeting invite in their calendar?

Comment: Have you considered using apps script for this? You can try to go through each calendar event and change the form URL attached to it with the event date prefilled. You can check this question as an example:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595815/set-pre-filled-value-of-google-form-item-from-google-apps-script

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was actually hoping for some "no-code" solution (similar to typing @today in a google doc in a calendar invite description that google calendar would automatically expand for each individual calendar invite)

But it might be worth to get familiar with app scripts.

Comment: Hi, did the link on the previous comment help you? If so set it as an answer or close this as a duplicate to let other users know what the answer is.