# Cannot refill a text input in google forms using apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following code:

```
  var existingForm = FormApp.openById('1qEsetweV0AXj2bw_APKjSVNS_d9iNaUbrtrtcjYm2vQ');
  var items = existingForm.getItems();
  var itemOfInterest;
  for(var i in items){
    if(items[i].getTitle()=="patient id"){
      itemOfInterest=items[i];
    }
  }

  var itemResponse = itemOfInterest.asTextItem().createResponse('my text');
```

It does not seem to refill the input text when opening the form, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108511/is-it-possible-to-prefill-a-google-form-using-data-from-a-google-spreadsheet/20110656#20110656 should show you how to setup a prefilled URL.

Comment: @JackBrown thnx that solved it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to 'prefill' a google form using data from a google spreadsheet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108511/is-it-possible-to-prefill-a-google-form-using-data-from-a-google-spreadsheet)