# Google Form - Filling one of the fields automatically from the email body

Tags: email, google-forms

I have a google form that is sent out each time a customer makes a purchase. The form has the below fields:

1. bill_no
2. customer_name
3. age
4. phone_number

This is sent out as an email with the bill_no and a google form link in the email body which the customer opens to fill the form.

I am trying to check if its possible to directly pass the bill_no that is present in the email body to the first question in the google form which asks for the bill_no. I do not want the customer to manually enter this bill_no but rather trying to see if it can be auto populated and the customer fills the remaining questions in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the section Send a form with prefilled answers on [Is it possible to 'prefill' a google form using data from a google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20108511/1595451)

Related

- [Is it possible to 'prefill' a google form using data from a google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20108511/1595451)