# How to request numeric keypad on Google Forms with Google Apps?

Tags: ios, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to use Google Forms to create an easy way for my mom to enter in her sales for work on her phone. Google Forms is free and gives some customization with how it exports to sheets.

Problem is that there are a few fields that need numbers entered in and I don't know how to request the numeric keyboard for entering in numbers. It would be a lot easier and quicker for her to use if I could get that numeric keyboard going.

I was also trying to figure out a way to automatically fill out the date section with a Google Apps script. I am not that familiar with Google scripts and was wondering if someone out there knows how to do all this.

Here's what the form looks like on mobile
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3EZF.png

This is the current keyboard that pops up.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkreY.png

This is an example of the numeric keyboard I'd like to have to enter in numeric data.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDy0z.png

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108511/

Comment: @TheMaster you should probably read the question, cause that thread is not related at all

Comment: @TheMaster the link you provided is 'prefill' a google form using data from a google spreadsheet? He is not using a google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

The html should only accept numbers. But, I don't think you can change html from within Google forms. Your options:

- Use Response validation to accept numbers only. It won't bring up  numeric keypad. But letters cannot be submitted.
- Create your own [form web-app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms) `<input type="number">` should force the numeric keyboard up.