# How to set a field by Url parameters in Google forms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm planning an [online survey](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd5krwc-5LouEkaU8wdWIrg_wLLU1emAhuo0KU5My3v09NYaA/viewform) about customers' orders.

[image]

But I don't want my user to fill `OrderId` field.

To solve this problem, I come to this solution:

1. Put the `OrderId` into the URL, so my link will be like this: `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd5krwc-5LouEkaU8wdWIrg_wLLU1emAhuo0KU5My3v09NYaA/viewform?orderId=12345`
2. Get the `orderId` from the URL, and put it to the `OrderId` field

But I faced 2 problems:

1. The forms open trigger is f[or editor open](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) instead of the user's open.

[image]

2. I found no way to get the current URL.

Could anyone give me some hint about these 2 problems?

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/20110656/ You need the url queryparameter key for `orderId` entry. It can be found when creating a prefilled url.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response?hl=en