# Create a Google Form from a Google Sheet using AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to create a Google Form from a Google Sheet using AppScript. I would then like the user link (the one to fill out the form) to be inserted back into the google sheet in a specific cell. I do not know if this makes any sense but I can try to provide clarification if needed.

I have not tried anything yet. I have no idea where to start.

[Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtBch.jpg)   [Google Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWINW.jpg)

Here is the link to the form https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdzwwGTQ3_LnqMMw3kUaWok-B1fk_Lv87PdfCHi7AA12uNUtA/viewform?usp=sf_link

Comment: I am sorry for the poor description of what I am trying to do. I have a spreadsheet that has the following questions:
How many apples are in the basket?
How many apples are red?
How many apples are green?
Is the basket full? (yes or no)

I would like to generate a google form with the questions that are listed in the cells. Then I would like to have the link for that Google form put back into a specific cell so that someone can click on that link and fill out the form.

Comment: @Tanaike I have included an example in my original post

Comment: Your form is not shared.

Comment: It has now been set to shared

Comment: Just pointing out that you might be able to get what you need via some existing extensions. I haven't tried any of these and most of them probably require some level of payment, but just from googling quickly there is https://www.mightyforms.com/blog/how-to-import-data-from-google-sheets-to-create-online-forms and https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/form_builder_for_sheets/463417060578

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to 'prefill' a google form using data from a google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108511/is-it-possible-to-prefill-a-google-form-using-data-from-a-google-spreadsheet)