# How to Add Office Use Section to Google Forms to allow review and validate user data

Tags: validation, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

I am looking at the possibility of converting a currently used paper-based data collection form to Google Forms.

This paper-based form has a section: For Office Use. This section is for secretariat  use to check if applicant meets criteria and approve application or reject otherwise.

```
SECTION A: Application Information
Name:.....................  Address:.............  Phone:.......................
...

SECTION B: For Office Use
Application Status:  Approved [   ]     Rejected [  ]
Reviewer Name:.............................       Date:.........................
```

I know that Google Forms responses are saved in a Google spreadsheet in Google drive, which can be edited later.

But is there a way to design the Forms to have the Office Use section so reviewer can review submitted responses before saving to Drive?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `But is there a way to design the Forms to have the Office Use section so reviewer can review submitted responses before saving to Drive?`. Can I ask you about both the detail of your current issue and your goal? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: You can't "hide" the Admin questions. I can think of two options. 1) **Manual review**: create form (no "Office Use" section), link to Sheets, `onFormSubmit` merge each response to a Google Doc (the "Office Use" section being part of the Doc), print Doc and complete review manually. OR 2) **100% digital**: create form (no "Office Use" section), link to same spreadsheet, different sheet; copy the form shell and create "Office Use" version; update user responses to "Office Use" form; create link to "Office Use" form, and complete review in form. Good precedents for both.

Comment: @Tedinoz the second option sounds interesting. Can you please elaborate on this, or mayb add an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have a Google Form that replaces a paper form; the paper form included an "Office Use" section and you want to retain this but am unsure whether and how this can be done.

It is NOT possible to hide questions. But the following answer enables a 100% digital solution. Bear in mind that there may be other ways to resolve this question.

**OVERVIEW**

- create a Google Form containing the user questions (without Office Use section) and link the responses to a new spreadsheet
- copy the "user questionnaire" form, name it for "Office Use", and link the responses to the same spreadsheet
- in the spreadsheet, use a script to create a profile of the item types and IDs in the "Office Use" form
- create an `onFormSubmit` script, as each user submission is received, use the responses to create a submission in the "Office Use" form.
- create a url to each "Office Use" submission so that the reviewer can edit complete "Section B" of the form.

**DETAILED STEPS**

**Step#1: Google Sheets - Part#1**

- create a new Google Sheets spreadsheet

  - you don't *need* a new spreadsheet but it simplifies building ands understanding this solution.

**Step#2: Google Form - Section A**

- create a Google form containing all the relevant "Section A" questions BUT *without* and "Section B" questions
- configure the form to export responses to the Google Spreadsheet created above.

**Step#3: Google Form - Section B**

- copy the "Section A" form and *add* the relevant questions for "Section B"
- configure the form to export responses to the Google Spreadsheet created above.
- copy a "pre-filled link" for the form.

  - provide answers to **all** the "Section A" questions.
  - where possible use a distinctive format for the answers such as **first_name**, **last_name**, **birthday"" and so on
  - where answers are multiple choice or dropdown, just select *any* answer.

**Step#4: Google Sheets - Part#2**

- the spreadsheet will contain two sheets for form responses: "Form Responses 1" for "Section A" and "Form Responses 2" for "Section B"

  - if you wish you can rename both sheets to something more informative; such as, "SectionA_form_responses" and/or "SectionB_form_responses".
- On sheet "SectionA_form_responses" insert an additional Column Header="Reviewer Link" to the right of the last column of form responses.

  - this is column in which the script will paste the url for the Section B review.

**Step#5: Sheets Project Editor**

- copy the script into the Project editior
- create an installable `onFormSubmit` trigger for `buildUrls(e)`
- "template" variable: replace the existing value with the "pre-filled link" obtained earlier.
- "values" variables: replace the variable names and Event Objects `values` array index to suit the data in "SectionA_form_responses"

  - FWIW, the script includes examples of the three methods of sourcing values: 1) Event Objects "values' array (as used in the script), 2) spreadsheet response value, 3) Event Objects "Named values"
- "url" variable: replace the distinctive placeholders and respective value variables

**PROCESSING**

**"Section A" form**

- each submission will update a row on "SectionA_form_responses"
  and
- insert a hyperlink in the "Reviewer Link" column of the same row of "SectionA_form_responses"

  - Note: each hyperlink carries pre-fill data for the respective respondent. The hyperlinks are NOT interchangeable.

**"Section B" form**

- the reviewer can click any hyperlink on "SectionA_form_responses"

  - this will open a new "Office Use" form pre-filled with data for the relevant applicant.
  - the reviewer can scan any/all the applicant answers.
  - when the reviewer completes the "Section B" part of the form, the submission updates a new row on the "SectionB_form_responses" sheet.

h/t: @Mogsdad [Is it possible to 'prefill' a google form using data from a google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20110656/1330560)

---

```
function buildUrls(e) {

  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG
  
  // update the 'template' variable from the pre-filled link
  var template = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScNM3gmrTM8m1eLvDQUhB_NZdm_SSlXWYGAoLlsH6PP-ahHaQ/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1360296307=**first_name**&entry.764247568=**last_name**&entry.1730236307=**employee_id**&entry.130080266=Cat+A"
  
  /*
  // assign values based on spreadsheet value
  var responseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("SectionA_Form_Responses")
  var responsedata = responseSheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  var editedRow = e.range.rowStart
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the edited row = "+editedRow)
  var firstName = responsedata[(editedRow-1)][1]
  var lastName = responsedata[(editedRow-1)][2]
  
  // assign values based on question text
  // Sample: "namedValues":{"Employee ID":["kfir"],"Job Category":["Cat C"],"Timestamp":["19/07/2023 17:54:35"],"First Name":["Mike"],"Last name":["Jones"]
  var firstName = e.namedValues["First Name"]
  var lastName = e.namedValues["Last name"]
  */

  // assign values based on array index
  // Sample: "values":["19/07/2023 17:54:35","Mike","Jones","k1423","Cat C"]
  var values = e.values
  var firstName = values[1]
  var lastName = values[2]
  var empID = values[3]
  var jobCat = values[4]

  // update url variables and values
  var url = template.replace('**first_name**',firstName)
    .replace('**last_name**',lastName)
    .replace('**employee_id**',empID)
    .replace('Cat+A',jobCat)  
  // Logger.log(url);  // DEBUG

  // find the column to insert the link
  var columnHeader = 'Reviewer Link'
  var headers = responseSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, responseSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
  var columnIndex = headers[0].indexOf(columnHeader);
  // Logger.log(columnIndex) // DEBUG
  var respRange = responseSheet.getRange(editedRow, columnIndex+1)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: target cell for review link = "+respRange.getA1Notation())
  var respName = responsedata[(editedRow-1)][1]+" "+responsedata[(editedRow-1)][2]
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Name: "+respName) 

  // insert link
  respRange.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + url + '", "' + respName + '")');

}
```

---

**SAMPLES**

**Form Section A**

[image: formsectionA]

---

**Responses Sheet - Form Section A**

[image: sheet form a]

---

**Form - Section B (created by hyperlink & showing pre-fill)**

[image: FormSectionB]

---

**Responses Sheet - Form Section B**

[image: sheet-section b]