# i want to auto fill google form by data in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, google-forms, google-workspace

i have this form
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc4OjEgxlYpcAO7zkd9-jLNvkB3nZRsrkMv-IqVII6EnL0DnQ/viewform

and i want to submit 100 response into it,

every response will be 4 answers only.

and i made the 4 answers in google spreadsheets in 4 columns A, B, C, D

and it's 100 rows and it can be more than 100

and data in A and B columns will be the same answer for all the 100 response

only data in B and C will change every submit.

can you help me in that ?

the data entry numbers are the following

entry.1359390460

entry.760502198

entry.1358984343

entry.650693243

And the pageHistory is 0,2,6

Can you guys help me in automate these data in the google spreadsheets to submit them into the google form successfully?

Comment: If it's your form (which begs the question of why are you doing this), you can create form responses. Go read up on that, try some, then ask for help.

Comment: i didn't say it's my form, it's public form and i have some data in google sheets and i want to fill the form response by the data into the google sheets. is this problem ? because i really don't understand your anger

Comment: Don't confuse apathy with Anger on stackoverflow. We aren't a cheerful bunch, nor are we an angry bunch -- kind of like people bots.  Nobody's mad at you, we just get a lot of low-caliber questions on here that are typically people just looking for free coding help. I actually will take the time to answer your question now that it's clear what's going on.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20110656/

Answer (score 0):

As was clarified in the comments, OP intends to create submissions to a FORM that is owned by someone else. It is not possible to do this using Google App scripts or any standardized Google tool.

While there are mechanisms that could probably accomplish this (python, autohotkey),  I would guess that Google has safe-guards to make this difficult such as "click here to prove your human". Automated form submissions from non-form owners would essentially be a security flaw as it would open the door for potential abuse (i.e. people flooding some form submission with thousands of garbage responses that were advertisements or something).

To your particular case, I'd contact the site or something and find anoter way to submit -- or just grind through it. I realize not ideal, but that's the answer to your question.

Comment: well, seems you took it too personal and i still sure you talk with anger and hate because i think this website help everyone have question, if someone else can help.

and if you talk about free help, and you sad for that, i think you should ask the owner of this site and make asking questions is a paid service. so ppl like you will be happy at the night...

and of course i'm not spamming it at all, because we almost in 2024 so why i would do that?