# Submit a Google Form response using HTTP POST

Tags: http, google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I want to submit a response to a Google Form using an HTTPS POST. This is described here:
[HTTP Post Request](https://dev.to/kvizdos/til-1-how-to-post-to-a-google-form-using-html-10ia). Here is the code sample for the review:

```html
<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/{formId}/formResponse" method="POST">
<div class="item">
<label>Your name</label>
<input name="entry.3403608" required type="text" placeholder="Kenton Vizdos" />
</div>
<div class="item">
<label>Your email</label>
<input name="entry.42966434" required type="email" placeholder="welcome@prauxy.app" />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Join">
</form>
```

This works great until using sections. For example, if I have two sections, then the data from the first section is submitted, but not the subsequent sections. Any guidance to resolve this is much appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code as text. - [format code] (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and please provide a [mcve]

Comment: this is not a code but a screenshot from the given website where it is provided as an image, thank you

Comment: It's hard to read for me

Comment: but then I don't have eagle eyes

Comment: you can check this if you want: https://dev.to/kvizdos/til-1-how-to-post-to-a-google-form-using-html-10ia

Comment: Sorry I don't follow links to offsite resource.  If you wish my help it has to be posted in the question.

Comment: EagleEye, the question needs to stand alone which means that any code should be included in the body of the question as text. Would you please edit the question to include the relevant code/script(s).

Comment: @Tedinoz, please check it now

Comment: If you use sections, I believe you need to submit repeatedly for each section. Have you checked how the actual Google form operates in sections(console, network and html, when submission)?

Comment: the aim is to use single post request to fill multiple sections of the form.

Comment: if you own the form, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108511/  might help

Comment: Just curious but, are the sections on your Google Forms necessary? It's because I wouldn't recommend using sections if you would want to submit a response via POST Request, even if using a generated pre-filled link where the Entry IDs are located there as well, it doesn't submit responses from the second section fo the form if you modify the POST Request URL by changing `viewform` to `formResponse?&submit=Submit?`